# Need Help on Inner Join two Query

Tags: sql

Hi Guys can you help me out to create this inner joint query.

the idea is I need to first get which is the top 3 highest keyword count then show that count of keyword per month (I need the Month Number only)

```
SELECT ReportRaw.Keyword, Format([DateApplying],'m') AS appdate, Count(ReportRaw.Keyword) AS CountOfKeyword1

FROM 

(
SELECT TOP 3 Count(Keyword) AS CountOfKeyword,Keyword
FROM ReportRaw
GROUP BY Keyword
ORDER BY Count(Keyword) DESC;
) as T1

INNER JOIN ReportRaw

ON T1.Keyword = ReportRaw.Keyword

GROUP BY ReportRaw.Keyword, Format([DateApplying],'m') ;
```

Comment: what is wrong with this query? show some sample output

Comment: I am getting a syntax error on "From" in my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that semicolon (;) after DESC. Assuming this is SQL Server

Made a tiny update to the query to get that month number:

```
SELECT #ReportRaw.Keyword, DATEPART(MONTH, [DateApplying]) AS appdate, 
 Count(#ReportRaw.Keyword) AS CountOfKeyword1
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP 3 Count(Keyword) AS CountOfKeyword,Keyword
    FROM #ReportRaw
    GROUP BY Keyword
    ORDER BY Count(Keyword) DESC
) as T1

INNER JOIN #ReportRaw
    ON T1.Keyword = #ReportRaw.Keyword
GROUP BY #ReportRaw.Keyword, DATEPART(MONTH, [DateApplying]) ;
```

Comment: Wow silly me Victimize by the semicolon again ( ~_~)`!!

Comment: @AkamiKurai i have modified the query (using a #temptable) to get that Month number, you must have already figured out.

Comment: Works Great Thanks!!